# Unable to connect to SSH / Network issue

Tags: networking, package-management, ssh, firewall, fail2ban

I know the information I'm providing is very limited but I lost SSH connection to my Ubuntu Mate (Odroid XU4).

I tried from different hosts, same issue, I also have very limited torrent connection from the Odroid.

I don't have firewall on the device, and I didn't change anything on the network.

My router intrusion protection keep detecting a Tor replay (which I'm dropping) bot that on a different port.

I didn't do much recently, I installed fail2ban a few days ago (not today) which can be a obvious link.

PS: All packages were installed by SSH, is there a way to order PKG installed by SSH , or all PKG listed by date of installation ?
I'm not to sure what to do though, how can I fix this?

UPDATE : I removed Fail2ban and the issue remains

Comment: Rebooting the device (XU4) might help, also you should use `ssh -vv ...`, and add the output to the question, cause it's somewhat vague as is.

Comment: Thank for the reply I actually fixed SsH by removing and reinstalling OPENSSH , not sure about the other issue, gonna run a test in a min